# getFullYear() in object

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why this is not working:

```
var todayDate = new Date();
var todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear();

var User = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  email: "email@email.com",
  dob: new Date(85, 1, 1),
  userBirthYear: dob.getFullYear(),
  age: todayYear - userBirthYear,
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  bio: "I love pizza",
  interests: ["food", "NBA", "movies"]
}
```

The `userBirthYear` doesn't seem to be initializing. If I move the `userBirthYear` outside the object as a separate variable, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dob` isn't a variable, it is a property of the User object.

But you can't directly access object properties until that whole object has been compiled

You could do it this way;

```
var User = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  email: "email@email.com",
  dob: new Date(85, 1, 1), 
  age: todayYear - userBirthYear,
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  bio: "I love pizza",
  interests: ["food", "NBA", "movies"]
}
// User object now exists, modify it any way you need
 User.userBirthYear = User.dob.getFullYear();
```

Comment: bad copy paste without changing to `=`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!